# I am trying to add a list of movies and rating into an unordered map in c++

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, maps, unordered-map

I am trying to add a long list of movies and rating into an unordered map or some type of array that would allow me to match by index.

I have another file that already iterates through the entire list. The only thing that I need to worry about is how to put the movies and rating into one index. My issue is that I keep getting an error on insert or ratings.

[Insert Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6871.png)

[Ratings error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4pCm.png)

I want to know if I am doing this correctly.

```
Movies(std::vector<std::string> movies, std::vector<int> ratings) {
   std::unordered_map<std::string, int> movielist;
   movielist.insert(movies, ratings);
}
```

I think this has something to do with the constructor arguments being vector but I don't know how to set it in a list.

I am quite new to C++ so I am not familiar with the specific syntax needed.

Comment: There's a lot to unpack here. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? Please go over [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Text should be reproduced as text. Images of text cannot be easily searched, exclude the visually impaired, are blocked by firewalls, there's a long list of reasons not to use images.

Comment: `moves` and `ratings` are vectors. You would have to iterate over them and insert each value into `movieList`.

Comment: You may want to aggregate the movies and ratings into a  structure and provide a `vector` of this structure. This eliminates the possibility of having a size mismatch between the two `vector`s.

Comment: The C++ associative containers like all other containers take `value_type` objects as parameters of `insert()`. Substitute `insert()` with `emplace()` and feed each pair of `movie`/`ratings` elements to them individually.